# How to apply a class if @Input is true in angular

Tags: css, angular

I have a variable I'm getting as input:

```
@Input()
public isNotReplay: boolean | false;
```

if this variable is true I want to apply a class with a style:

```
.main-chat {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I've gotten this to work with the terinary operator like this:

```
<div class="message-container" [ngClass]="isNotReplay ? 'main-chat' : 'some-other-class'">
```

however, I only want to apply my main-chat class if it's true and not have to use some-other-class. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options, but I think what you are looking for is the following:
`<div class="message-container" [ngClass]="{ 'main-chat':isNotReplay }">`

`ngClass` can take an object. The object properties are the classes that will be given to the HTML element conditionally, based on the property's value.

For whatever its worth, you're code : `@Input() public isNotReplay: boolean | false;` looks like it should probably be `@Input() public isNotReplay: boolean = false;`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div [class.class-name]="isNotReplay"></div>
```

Comment: I think you were correct before the edit(`[class.class-name]`): https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding

Comment: would the class.class-name be replaced by my class name? so for example, should it read: [class.main-chat]="isNotReplay"